# Произношение: "шинЭль" или "шинЕль"?

Tags: фонетика

Помню, в школе нас всегда поправляли, если кто-то произносил "шинЭль". Говорили, что правильно мягко - "шинЕль". А что говорят об этом нормы русского языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь шла о гоголевских временах, то тогда, если ни с чем не путаю, произношение было твердым. Вообще большинство французских (отчасти и других заимствований) слов тогда следовали фонетике языка-источника.
Правда во французском Н там полумягкое (chenille), но русским ухом воспринимается скорее как твердое. Кстати, не в последнюю очередь поэтому "шиниль" и превратилось в "шинель".
Но это все - история. Сейчас в любом словаре есть помета типа "шинель (не Э)".

Comment: Поправочка: не "chinille", a "ChEnille".

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю. В заимствованных словах после согласных на месте буквы Е обычно произносится Э. По мере освоения слова произношение меняется и  становится, как в русских словах - перед Е произносится мягкий. В разных конкретных случаях это занимает разный промежуток времени. Слово свитер, например, по рекомендациям словарей, надо произносить с твердым Т.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно поправляли, в этом слове звук Н - мягкий.

Answer (score 0):

Произносится мягко: шинЕль.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда знала и прозношу шинЕль, так в школе учили.

Comment: Правильно, только не стоит ссылаться на школу. Это не тот источник, который тут будет считаться авторитетным.